# How do I use both xibs and storyboard in my program?

Tags: uitableview, ios5, storyboard, nib

I've made a project based completely on xibs. Now I need to add a table view whose cells will lead into the xibs I have in my project. All of the tutorials I've found for table view use storyboard, so I was wondering, how I would go about building the table view in storyboard in my current project and then having the detail view be my xibs? If that's not possible, would I have to start a new project that uses storyboard and then add all my xibs into the project? Finally, I think the easiest solution is to make a table view using xibs, not storyboard. Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

Please let me know if my question is unclear or if you need my information. The last question I posted was left unanswered because I didn't ask correctly and I still have no idea why...so I don't want that to happen again.

The help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add storyboards into a mainly xib based project but as you said using UITableView with xibs is what you would prefer and yes, you can do this.

If you go to File > New File > Objective-C Class > subclass UITableViewController. Tell it to make you a xib. This will implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource for you. Then you just need to provide it the necessary methods and it should work from there.

Here is a good tutorial that may help you: http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/ (some of this is not relevant if you subclass UITableViewController because it will automatically establish the Delegate and DataSource properties).

Also, feel free to ask any questions if something does not make sense. I am a bit unsure as to what you are after exactly so my answer may not be perfect.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this out when I get back to class and let you know how it went or if any problems occurred.